# More iPhone 4 resolution scaling fun

Tags: ios4, interface-builder, resolution, scaling

So I have two images set to fill the screen - one at 320x480 (iPhone 3) and the other at 640x960 (iPhone 4).

```
img.png      (320x480)
img@2x.png   (640x960)
```

In Interface Builder, I have img.png set to fill the view (it shouldn't be filling the iPhone 4 view, though, right?), and when I build and run, it is notably too small.

So, when I do the opposite, setting img@2x.png as the img, a giant blue question mark fills the view. The project still builds and the image fills the screen, but is very pixelated as if it has been rescaled. It shouldn't have been rescaled, though, as it is the higher resolution.

Now using...

```
img.png      (640x960)
img@2x.png   (320x480)
```

I've also tried switching which file takes the @2x suffix, but that has not helped either. With the smaller file taking the @2x suffix, and setting the image view to img.png, it shows up way larger than the view canvas, but way too small when on the phone. With the smaller file still having the @2x suffix, I tried switching the view to the new img@2x.png and once again got the oversized, pixelated question mark in IB and a low res full-screen image when deployed to the phone.

I also made sure that my view size was set to 640x960 in the size inspector. What else should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `@2x` when specifying the image name. Just use the base name of the image (so in your case, just `img`). iOS will do the magic behind the scenes to use the 2x version if it's on a retina display and the regular version otherwise (including when you use a xib to lay out your interface).

The displayed dimensions of the image will always be the dimensions of the non-2x image. The retina display just displays 2 pixels for every 1 which is why the scale is 2.0 and you have to double the dimensions of the original image. So your view size in IB should be 320x480.

**Edit**

If IB is being finicky, especially in Xcode 4, just try deleting the xib and starting over. Sometimes it gets a bit corrupted and doesn't know what to do with itself. I've had to do this on one or two occasions, and it seems that it worked for the OP as well.

Comment: So, you're saying to set the image view to 320x480 and the image to img.png, but still use the @2x in one of the file names. Which one gets the @2x? The larger one because it is 2x the size or the smaller one because it must be scaled 2x? Haha

Comment: The image view size should be 320x480. `img.png` should be 320x480 pixels and `img@2x.png` should be 640x960 pixels.

Comment: Okay, so I tried both, and both show up as teeny tiny on the screen.

Comment: You're using a `UIImageView`, right? Is the image property set to `img`? And you have both `img.png` and `img@2x.png` in your project, right?

Comment: That's strange. Image view size is 320x480, img.png is 320x480, and img@2x.png is 640x960, and in IB everything looks fine, but when I run it on the phone, the whole image view is shrunk to half size with a white background around it.

Comment: That is very strange indeed. That certainly should not be happening. As far as I can tell you have everything set up correctly. You sure you don't have any rogue properties set you forgot about, or any code that might be changing things?

Comment: Yes on all three counts, so I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode and IB can be finicky. Are you using the XC4 beta or XC 3.x? If you're using the beta, try just deleting the xib and starting again. That's honestly solved problems for me in the past. Sad, I know.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the new .xib a shot. Using Xcode 3.2.5, but was about to install 4 (After multiple failed downloads... another strange tale, there. Hah.)

Comment: So, it turns out starting fresh seemed to do the trick. Now oddly enough my icon now only looks right when the plist file points directly to the @2x (114x114) icon.

Comment: @Marc W - Can you add the "deleting the xib and starting again" part to your answer for the SO community? This was part of the fix. Thanks.

Comment: Good idea. It's in there now.